# Error on gradle-2.10-all.zip.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently updated my Android Studio to  the recent version of 2.1.3 and also did some other update that popped up, only to obtain this error below for all my already existing projects on my android studio.

> Error:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\gradle\gradle-2.2.1\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst\gradle-2.10-all.zip.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)

Please Guys I need your assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Visit https://services.gradle.org/distributions and download the desired gradle version (in your case gradle-2.10-all.zip) and place it in "C:\Users\your_user_name\ .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst\put_it_here"  folder and sync project again.

Comment: this is perfect answer

Comment: does'nt android create these files on its own in .gradle?q

Answer (score 3):

> Error:C:\Users\Aman.gradle\caches\3.3\scripts-remapped\build_9xilmbs31p63j7oau8p3qxxmv\d0u1sorhwxy5ca3j4lgnxtkce\cp_proj1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3\cache.properties
>   (The system cannot find the file specified)

Solution: just go to gradle.wrapper.properties and then,

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4-all.zip
```

Change in url just increase the gradle version like 2.10 to 2.11 it will work. Then sync the project.

Comment: Helpful solution

Answer (score 1):

The steps given below may solve your problem :

1) Create a new Android project.

2) Then open the build.gradle(Module:app) file(of your new project).

3) copy the dependencies

example :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

4) Add them to your old project which is giving error.

5) Also see the

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

They should match with what ever is written after v7 support library (android_support_lib_version).

6) Finally sync the project once again.

Comment: I followed the instructions you provided and yet I still had the same error after syncing the project. Maybe I will have to uninstall my android studio and delete all files related to android and then do a re-installation, because I have checked and followed a whole lot of similar instructions from questions related to the issue I am facing and still yet no solution. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: okay.. but i would recommend that instead of uninstalling and then installing again you can directly download and install new version of SDK and it should work.

Comment: How do I do that? Should I prompt the Android studio to do that or will I have to download it manually? Hope you got my question?

Comment: download it manually from here - http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest (andriod 2.2 beta)

Comment: Oh I see I should update the android studio rather than re-installing afresh? OK. Let me give it a trial then.

Comment: When i did the upgrade you requested after downloading the patch, i added the patch which upgraded my android studio to Android Studio 2.2 Beta , but i still had the error. What i finally did was to resolve the path directory to my sdk, i had like two different sdks sdk and sdk2 so what i actually did was to uninstall the android studio and get a fresh copy and as well did delete all the android related paths and files and voila i got it working after the numerous task of installing and deleting.

Comment: okay that's great.. kindly answer your own question this will help other  people also :)

Comment: This problem is only coming in windows

Answer (score 1):

you should download the appropriate version from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

and then place the zip file inside c:\users\your name.gradle\wrapper\dists[gradle-v-all\guid]
[image]

so when you open your android studio starts, it will unzip the zip file. If you try placing the content of the zip file it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem when i was open my previous project. It just download Gradle 3.3 all from Online and after that i found that Error.
In my case I solved that issue just Change

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

**Because previously I have already downloaded in this Directory since my Android studio was updated to 3.2.1**

**C:\Users\your_name.gradle\wrapper\dists**